# Mellin transformation in a coordinate vector form

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, ads-cft

In QFT, we usually deal with Fourier transformation. In AdS space, there is a similar formulation called "Mellin transformation" I want to know some physical expression of Mellin transformation for generic tensor(or coordinate vector) $X^{\mu}$.

First, let me explain the form of Fourier transformation in one variable and extend it to $X=(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$, i.e., coordinate vector form which is frequently used in physics.

\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\zeta_1) = \int dx_1 f(x_1) e^{-2\pi i x_1 \zeta_1}
\end{align}
If we expand this to $X=(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ then one can write
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\zeta) = \int dX f(X) e^{-2 \pi i X \cdot \zeta}
\end{align}
here $\zeta=(\zeta_1, \cdots, \zeta_n)$, due to $X\cdot \zeta = \sum_i x_i \zeta_i$, the multivariable Fourier expansion form has such nice form.

But how about Mellin transformation?  It seems a similar thing does not well defined.

The Mellin transformation of single variable is defined as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}(f) = \int_0^{\infty} f(t_1) t_1^{s_1 -1} dt_1
\end{align}
Due to [my previous posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340473/multi-variable-mellin-transformation-and-its-inverse-transformation), I know multivariable Mellin transformation is given by
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}(f) = \int_0^{\infty} \cdots \int_0^{\infty} dt_1 \cdots dt_n t_1^{s_1-1} \cdots t_n^{s_n-1} f(t_1, \cdots, t_n)
\end{align}
I want to express this expression with $T=(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$ and $S=(s_1, \cdots, s_n)$ like I did in the Fourier case $X, \zeta$.

But it seems it is not possible to write down the Mellin transformation in tersm of $S=(s_1, \cdots, s_n)$ with $T=(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$ something like $T\cdot S$ or physics oriented form.

If you know some references or any ideas please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: How about $t_n \rightarrow \exp(\ln(t_n))$?

Comment: @flippiefanus, Actually my first trial is the same as your suggestion i.e.,  write $exp((s_n-1)ln(t_n))$ but I think Its form is not nice in terms of $T$ and $S$ and that's why I post a question here

Comment: Why do you say it is not nice?

Comment: I am thinking of extending or generalizing Ads correlators (or Mellin amplitudes) in terms of AdS coordinates $X$, not its coordinate form $X=(X_+, X_0, X^\mu)$. Naively I can do this with the similar form of Fourier transform as setting $x_i=e^{t_i}$ and introducing new coordinates, but due to my motivation (I am thinking some particular form of $f$ which is a function of $X\cdot P$ where $X$ is a bulk of Ads and $P$ is a boundary of AdS), such setting is not nice for me.

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you there. It is a bit open ended.